# При запуске телеграм бота игра "виселица" работет неправильно

Tags: python, разработка-игр, telegram, бот

```
import random
import telebot
spisok=('автострада','спасибо')
a=random.choice(spisok)
b=(list(a))
n=list(("*"*len(a)))

bot = telebot.TeleBot("108...T")
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет,сейчас ты сыграешь в игру виселица")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''.join(n))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите одну букву")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    s=0 
    while True: 
        if message.text in b:
            for idx, symbol in enumerate(b):
                if symbol == message.text:
                    n[idx] = symbol
            if n==b:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы выиграли")
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поздравляю")
        else:   
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Данной буквы нет")
            s+=1
            if s==5:
                return



    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ''.join(n))
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Если я ввожу правильную букву и отгадываю слово,то прогорамма работает корректно.Если же я ввожу неправильную букву, то бот 5 раз присылает сообщение "данной буквы нет"

Answer (score 0):

Это из-за переменной s, смысл которой непонятен (видимо, как раз для того, чтобы вывести этот текст пять раз).

Comment: а как мне тогда реализовть, чтобы при 5 неверных введенных буквах, программа завершает работу?

Comment: это там боевой токен, да?